# How to fix "arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime" after specific declaration of variables in power bi?

Tags: sql, variables, powerbi-desktop, declare

Before power bi I'd been using my sql in excel and everything was smooth. But  in power bi i got "arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime". Is there something wrong with my declaration or what:?
Thats what i had in Excel:

[image]

Thats how i recode it in power bi

```
let
    SQLSource = (PrevDate as date, CurrDate as date) =>
let
    Source = Sql.Database("DKB-00-02", "Stat_DKB", [Query="

SET NOCOUNT ON
UPDATE STATISTICS Stat_DKB.dbo.[BalanceDKB]; 
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
SELECT * FROM [Stat_DKB].[dbo].[BalanceDKB_DeltaFor2Dates] ("& Date.ToText(PrevDate,"yyyyMMdd") & ","& Date.ToText(CurrDate,"yyyyMMdd") & ",1000000,1)
where [Credit_Deposit] = 'Deposit'
"])

in
    Source
in
    SQLSource
```

and then goes my error. Are there any ideas where the heart of the matter?

Comment: Did you already refer to this resource? https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/parameters-to-SP-or-Sql-query/m-p/58337

Comment: @StringTheory no, thanks, but I haven't found there solution of mine

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider replacing the following line:

```
SELECT * FROM [Stat_DKB].[dbo].[BalanceDKB_DeltaFor2Dates] ("& Date.ToText(PrevDate,"yyyyMMdd") & ","& Date.ToText(CurrDate,"yyyyMMdd") & ",1000000,1)
```

With this one, so as to include the apostrophe that surrounds the date values:

```
SELECT * FROM [Stat_DKB].[dbo].[BalanceDKB_DeltaFor2Dates] ('" & Date.ToText(PrevDate,"yyyyMMdd") & "','" & Date.ToText(CurrDate,"yyyyMMdd") & "',1000000,1)
```